# Training U-Net on one label form multi labels mri image (using Monai or Pytorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am training a U-Net using Monai, which is based on Pytorch. I am using Decathlon Dataset, where each segmentation image has two labels (one for the organ and the other for the tumour). What I want is to ignore the first label (organ segmentation) and train the network on the second label (tumour segmentation). I don't know if I should delete one label from the images manually(This will take me a lot of time if I have hundreds of images). Is there a way to do it using code? What is the right way to do it? Is there any existing function in Monai? Because Opening each image as a tensor, reading its values and replacing label 1 with the background pixel might be time and resource-consuming. Thanks

I tried to search on Monai docs to get a simple code but I didn't find.

Comment: what does the training code look like? there's got to be "data loading". that's where you can filter the dataset for your desired labels only (and probably adjust the class ids, surely the output layer to accomodate the reduced number of classes).

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz thanks for your reply. I am using the same code: https://github.com/amine0110/Liver-Segmentation-Using-Monai-and-PyTorch